# Имеет ли смысл каскадно оборачивать блоки try-catch друг в друга?

Tags: c#, winforms, исключения, try-catch

Есть такой код:

```
if (e.Error == null)
{
    if (MessageBox.Show(
        "Обновление готово. Текущая программа будет закрыта, будет запущен загрузчик новой. Не удаляйте исполняемые файлы программы. Вы согласны?",
        "Все готово",
        MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel,
        MessageBoxIcon.Information) == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        again: if ( ! File.Exists(@"info.txt"))
        {
            try
            {
                File.WriteAllText(@"info.txt", Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location.ToString()));
                try
                {
                    Process.Start(filename);
                    Application.Exit();
                }
                catch { Error("Установщик обновления не найден"); }
            }
            catch { Error("Не удалось записать в файл info.txt"); }
        }
        else
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show(
                "При попытке обновления возникла ошибка:\n\nФайл info.txt уже существует\n\nУдалить его?",
                "Ошибка",
                MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, 
                MessageBoxIcon.Error) == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                if (File.Exists(@"info.txt")) try { File.Delete(@"info.txt"); } catch { }
                goto again;
            }
        }
    }
}
else Error(e.Error.Message);
```

**Вопрос**: перегружен ли этот код? Имеет ли смысл так часто использовать блоки `try-catch`?

Comment: Если выкидываются исключения разного класса, то можно запихнуть всё в один try с несколькими catch, в которых ловятся ошибки определённого класса

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У вашего кода довольно много проблем.

1. Слишком много логики набросано в кучу, получается спагетти. Минус сорок к читабельности. Разбейте код на осмысленные процедуры.
2. Строковые константы разбросаны по коду. Ещё минус двадцать к читабельности. Вынесите их отдельно как константы, заодно и потом легче будет менять язык в случае чего. И искать тоже будет легче, и менять.
3. Вы ловите все исключения! Минус тридцать к отладке непонятных проблем в будущем. Так делать нельзя (об этом написано везде), ловите только специфические исключения. Да, код будет сложнее, кто говорил, что будет просто?
4. Вы гоняете бесконечный цикл попыток удаления info.txt, надоедая юзеру бесконечными месседжбоксами. Если вы один раз не смогли удалить этот файл, почему вы предполагаете, что во второй раз вы сможете, неужели что-то поменялось? Минус пятьдесят к впечатлению пользователя о программистах вообще и о вашей программе в частности.

Ещё одна возможная проблема — вы соединяете код модели (проверка обновления) и представления (информирование пользователя), вы не сможете использовать этот код для фонового обновления.

Вот что у меня вышло после подчистки:

```
if (e.Error != null)
{
    Error(e.Error.Message);
    return;
}

if (!ConfirmStartUpdater())
    return;
if (!PrepareInfo())
    return;
if (!StartUpdater(filename))
    return;
Application.Exit();

// --------------------------

bool ConfirmStartUpdater()
{
    var dialogResult = MessageBox.Show(
        Strings.ConfirmUpdateMessage, Strings.ConfirmUpdateCaption,
        MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    return (dialogResult == DialogResult.OK);
}

bool PrepareInfo()
{
    if (File.Exists(@"info.txt"))
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show(
                Strings.ConfirmDeleteInfo, Strings.ErrorCaption,
                MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Error) != DialogResult.OK)
            return false;

        try
        {
            File.Delete(@"info.txt");
        }
        catch (IOException ex) // остальные ловить нельзя, чтобы случайно
        {                      // не скрыть баг в программе
            // тут надо не забыть сообщить об ошибке юзеру
            return false;
        }
    }

    try
    {
        var location = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(
                           Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location.ToString());
        File.WriteAllText(@"info.txt", location);
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        Error("Не удалось записать в файл info.txt");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

bool StartUpdater(string filename)
{
    try
    {
        Process.Start(filename);
    }
    catch (посмотрите сами, что тут надо ловить)
    {
        Error("Установщик обновления не найден");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: *"Если вы один раз не смогли удалить этот файл, почему вы предполагаете, что во второй раз вы сможете, неужели что-то поменялось?"* — Скажите это винде, которая делает 10 попыток с разрывом в 1 секунду (или полсекунды?), если удалять файлы функциями оболочки...

Comment: @Discord но винда при этом сообщение об ошибке выводит только если *все* попытки оказались неудачными, а не после каждой

Comment: @Discord: У винды не такой юзкейс. Если файл виден у меня в эксплорере, и я удаляю его, то с хорошими шансами я работал с ним несколько секунд назад, и только что закрыл приложение. Которое может умирать слишком медленно. Это валидный, часто реализующийся юзкейс. Для случая файла с данными для обновления, залоченный файл — не валидный юзкейс, а ошибка. Этот файл не предназначен для того, чтобы нормальный юзер с ним работал. (А ненормальный сам знает, что делает.)

Answer (score 1):

Вообще подобный подход далеко не самый продуктивный.

Лучшее все критические условия выполнения какой-либо операции проверять до её запуска, а в исключениях перехватывать критические ошибки связанные непосредственно с процессом работы алгоритма.

Проверку существования установщика обновления и файла `info.txt` вполне можно выполнить предварительно с помощью условного оператора (`if`). В тоже время ошибку записи в файл `info.txt` или другие неполадки связанные непосредственно с выполнением тех или иных действий лучше оставить в блоке перехвата исключений.

Попытаюсь продемонстрировать вышесказанное на **псевдокоде** (один из возможных вариантов):

```
if (файлСуществует && установщикОбновленияСуществует)
{
    try
    {
        // Запускаем установщик обновления и пишем информацию в файл
    }
    catch
    {
        //Выводим ошибку
    }
}
```

Как-то так...

Answer (score 1):

Лучше разбить вложенные try-catch для лучшей читаемости

```
try
  {
  File.WriteAllText(@"info.txt", Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location.ToString()));
  }
catch { 
  Error("Не удалось записать в файл info.txt"); 
  return;
      }
try
  {
  Process.Start(filename);
  Application.Exit();
  }
catch { Error("Установщик обновления не найден"); }
```